# Настройка вывода виджета CGrdiView (Yii)

Tags: php, yii

Мне нужно внести некоторые изменения в выводе виджета CGrdiView, а именно:

- Поменять местами **поле ввода поиска по полю** и **название поля** ;
- Уменьшить ширину столбца;

Не знаю как сделать.

[image]

[Скриншот](http://s17.postimg.org/hv6501qxb/screen1.jpg)

Code: [PHP code view!](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/ci8-32d)

**P.S. Простите, если вопрос очень глупый, просто я новичок )**

Comment: @frops код представления в студию.

Comment: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/ci8-32d

Comment: @frops т.е. вам нужно всю строку с формой поместить вверх, над таблицей?

Comment: @frops плюсанул. Таки узнал для себя что-то новое.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Чтобы уменьшить ширину столбцов, напишите в файле стилей вот это:

```
.grid-view table.items {width: auto;}
```

Дополню ответ пользователя **zenith**, поскольку он меня немного опередил
Ссылка на документацию по **[CGridView](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CGridView#filterPosition-detail)**
Ваш код, с учетом этих изменений:

```
<?php

$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'dataProvider' => $model->search(),
    'filter' => $model,
    'filterPosition' => 'header', //Устанавливаем позицию фильтра
    'htmlOptions' => array(
        'class' => 'table table-hover table-striped',
    ),
    'columns' => array(
        array(
            'name' => 'id',
        ),
        array(
            'name' => 'create_time',
            'value' => 'date("d-m-Y H:i:s", $data->create_time)',
            'filter' => false,
        ),
        array(
            'name' => 'status',
        ),
        array(
            'header' => 'Длина текста',
            'value' => 'mb_strlen(trim(strip_tags($data->text)), "utf-8")',
        ),
        array(
            'header' => 'Отправитель',
            'name' => 'user.email',
        ),
        array(
            'header' => 'Права доступа',
            'name' => 'user.role',
        ),
        array(
            'class' => 'CButtonColumn',
        ),
    )
));
?>
```

Comment: .grid-view table.items {width: auto;} Не помогает. Я даже новый класс добавил, в "fire bug" вижу, что CSS-свойство стоит. Но это никак не влияет. Пробовал даже .grid-view table.items td {width: auto;}

Comment: Я написал 100% рабочий пример для кода, сгенерированного с помощью gii (стандартный класс у таблицы - items). Проинспектируйте таблицу, где у вас выводятся данные. Если у нее стоит в свойствах стилей **width: 100%** - удалите это свойство с помощью firebug и посмотрите, достигните ли вы нужного эффекта. В моем случае именно это и сработало. По умолчанию в html-таблице столбцы выравниваются **по ширине содержимого**. Так что если вы им (или input'ам) не переназначали стили, все должно работать.

Comment: Я вроде понял все, но не получается. Вот скриншот: http://clip2net.com/s/5pt6po

Comment: @VenZell Все прояснилось. Там просто сам input весь столбец растягивал, так как я использую Twitter Bootstrap. Спасибо большое за помощь ))

Answer (score 2):

Кажется вам нужно это:

> **filter (с v1.1.1)** [[@var](/users/442/varezzz)](/users/442/varezzz) CModel
> экземпляр модели, содержащей введенные
> пользователем фильтрующие данные. Если
> данное свойство установлено, таблица
> активирует фильтрацию для данного
> столбца. Каждый столбец данных по
> умолчанию отображает наверху таблицы
> текстовое поле, которое пользователь
> может заполнить фильтрующими данными.
> Примечание: для того, чтобы показать
> поле ввода для фильтрации, столбец
> должен иметь установленное свойство
> CDataColumn::name или свойство
>
> **filterPosition (с v1.1.1)**
> [[@var](/users/442/varezzz)](/users/442/varezzz) string отображать ли фильтры
> таблицы. Допустимые значения:      
>     header: фильтры отображаются наверху каждого столбца в
> ячейке-заголовке;
>     body: фильтры отображаются сразу за ячейкой-заголовком;
>     footer: фильтры отображаются ниже ячейки-футера.

от [сюда](http://progergirl.blogspot.ru/2012/05/cgridview_27.html)